# addition consecutive number interval of different groups r

Tags: r, numbers, sum

I have large vector with the following type:

```
myvec <- c(1,2,3,5,  0,1,2,5,8,  0,1,3,  0,2,3,8,  0,3,5)
```

The corresponding vector for group is:

```
grp <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 5), rep(3,3), rep(4, 4), rep(5, 3))
```

I need to add the number such way that the last number of consecutive group will be added to the distance in second group plus 2 (to create a gap). Then last number of second group will added to third pus 3 to create a gap.

thus new vector will look like

```
       myvecnew <- c(1,  2, 3 ,5,  # maximum 5 + 2 applied in group 2

     5+0+2 = 7, 5+1+2 = 8, 5+2+2 = 9, 5+5+2 = 12, 8+5+2 = 15, # maximum 15 + 2 applied in group 3

       0+15+2 = 17, 1+15+2 = 18, 3+15+2 = 20, # maximum 20 + 2 applied to group 4 

                  0 + 20 + 2 = 22,..........and so on)
```

Thus max(value) of group 1 plus 2 is added to every group 2 values, the resulting new maximum for group 2 will be added to group 3 plus the constant 2, and I need to keep going till all groups are covered. 
How can this be achieved? ........

Comment: Shouldn't the second group have length 5? i.e. `grp <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 5), rep(3,3), rep(4, 4), rep(5, 3))`?

Comment: I think another error in the question is that when you get to `myvecnew`, the maximum for group 2 (8+5+2=15) is added to group 3, but I don't see the extra 'plus the constant 2' being added. @JohnCLK , please check this.

Comment: @JohnColby thank you for the correction ...I corrected them ..thank you for understanding what I meant by though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through what I think are 2 errors in the question (see comments), I believe you can achieve what you want like:

```
grps   = lapply(unique(grp), function(x) myvec[grp==x])
to.add = cumsum(sapply(grps, max) + 2)

> c(grps[[1]], unlist(lapply(2:length(grps), function(x) grps[[x]] + to.add[x-1])))
 [1]  1  2  3  5  7  8  9 12 15 17 18 20 22 24 25 30 32 35 37
```

(As you can see, I would also prefer to work with lists)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i in unique(grp)[-1])
{
    myvec[which(grp==i)]=
            2 +
            myvec[which(grp==i)]+
            max(myvec[which( grp==(i-1) )])
}
```

Comment: This gives me `1  2  3  5  6  7  8 11 14 16 17 19 22 24 25 30 34 37 39`, which doesn't match `myvecnew` in the question: `1 2 3 5 7 8 9 12 ...`